# Webview slow in emulator, works fine on device. Should I be concerned about beta-testing?

Tags: android, webview, genymotion

I am using Genymotion and am using the AdvancedWebView library. The basic Webview and other libraries had the same problems. The code is very basic. Just showing an already-mobile friendly website.

The webview on the emulator is very laggy and slow loading when scrolling. However, when I push the APK to the device, the app runs as intended and is very fast and snappy.

I only have 1 Android device and I wanted to beta-test it across other devices to make sure d other components don't crash inside the webview. Is this a huge concern?

Comment: Nope. Webviews are slower!

Comment: As a general rule, don't rely too much on the emulators (even though they have become better over last few updates) and do yourself a favour and test on real devices also.
We've actually moved away from Genymotion because it's quite buggy and they crash a lot.
If you're concerned about your app getting tested, you could try to make an open beta for people to try out.

Comment: That's something the Genymotion team knows already and a fix is on its ways to make the WebView faster. Maybe the next version will contain the patch.

Comment: It's been two years now, Genymotion 3 is out, and WebView is as slow as always. Makes Genymotion useless for testing and using the entire class of apps that relay on WebView